# centos7 can't install lftp

Tags: centos7, yum

I am trying to install `lftp` on my centos 7 server to mirror the content of directory in my old server, but `yum install` says `No package lftp available.`

I am a noobie ... I know that I should add the url of the rpm package to yum but I don't know how and don't know which url to add ...

`[root@dominoserver ~]# rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64`

Can someone please help ...

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7 `lftp` could be installed from `base` repo. Check you `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file and check that `base` repo enabled.

My section for `base` repo:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Comment: Package epel-release-7-12.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: @Exlord I'm sorry checked on new CentOS server and found that it should be in `base` repo. Updated answer.